# How to group multiple parcels at one using PHP

Tags: php, math, formula, volume

I need a formula which can help me to group multiple parcels at one.

I have a Parcel Object like this one:

```php
<?php

class Parcel {
    function __construct($length,$width,$height,$weight) {
        $this->length=$length;
        $this->width=$width;
        $this->height=$height;
        $this->weight=$weight;
    }

    private $length;
    private $width;
    private $height;
    private $weight;

    public function getParcelDetails()
    {
        echo "length=".$this->length."<br>";
        echo "width =".$this->width."<br>";
        echo "height=".$this->height."<br>";
        echo "weight=".$this->weight ."<br>";
    }

    public static function mergeParcels($parcels){
        $new_parcel_length=0;
        $new_parcel_width=0;
        $new_parcel_height=0;
        $new_parcel_weight=0;
        foreach ($parcels as $key => $parcel) {
            # What is the formula that can create a new parcel which is enable to contain the parcels $parcels?

            # The weight will be just additionned
            $new_parcel_weight+=$parcel->$weight;
        }

        $new_parcel= new static($new_parcel_length,$new_parcel_width,$new_parcel_height,$new_parcel_weight);

        return $new_parcel;
    }
}
```

The goal is to merge to parcels into one, so in the main script I'll have something like this:

```php
$parcel1=new Parcel(10,10,10,1);
$parcel2=new Parcel(5,5,5,1);

//$parcel1->getParcelDetails();
//$parcel2->getParcelDetails();

$new_parcel=Parcel::mergeParcels([$parcel1,$parcel2]);

$new_parcel->getParcelDetails();
```

This picture can demonstrate the problem:
[image]

Please note that the problem is when I have multiple parcels where dimensions are not equal.

If the dimensions are equal, I can just add them to each other, but I don't really have a solution when dimensions are not the same.

Comment: PHP or Java? Are you sure? Your code is just PHP.

Comment: See the picture. What should happen if I only have parcel 1, 2, and 3, then tried to merge them? should it become a non-box shaped?

Comment: @AITMANSOURMohamed but the code would be significantly different, if you just want the formula, it might be better off at: https://math.stackexchange.com/ - check their tour before you ask though.

Comment: @RizkiHadiaturrasyid no it might have a box shape, even if there is some free space,

Answer (score 2):

The programming problem you have is called a [knapsack packing problem](https://www.google.com/search?q=3d+knapsack+packing+problem), a subset of combinatorial optimization problems.

Small problems can be solved with dynamic programming, and larger ones with heuristics.

You can read more about it [here](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Heuristic-approaches-for-the-two-and-knapsack-Egeblad-Pisinger/f6917488ff3947ed5736727a15f40dd8d19cb2e9) and [here](https://di.ku.dk/forskning/Publikationer/tekniske_rapporter/2006/06-13.pdf).

Note that large-scale combinatorial solvers is an entire industry in itself, requiring years of R&D.